# No se detectan cambios cuando trato de hacer migraciones mientras que models.py fue modificado

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Modifiqué el models.py pero cuando intento hacer las migraciones me conteste el
compliador que no hay ninguna:

```
>>>python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
```

Mis intentos de resolución del problema:

- Como puede verlo sobre la imagen tengo una carpeta `migrations`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- `python manage.py makemigrations -v 3` no me da mas informaciones

## Actualizacion

En la mia carpeta principal del proyecto, en `settings.py` hay la app:

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'todo'
]
```

Comment: Es evidente que debes registrar tu app, ademas de que es una de las cosas mas básicas de Django...

Answer (score 2):

En tu carpeta principal del proyecto debes de tener un archivo llamado settings.py ahi encontraras

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'applications.bancos', #ejemplo
    'applications.users', #ejemplo
    'applications.productos',#ejemplo
    'applications.imagenes' #ejemplo
]
```

Ahi debes de colocar tu ruta de tu app para que lo registre una vez que tengas tu app en installed_apps te va a reconocer los cambios con makemigrations